# How to remove repeat values in index group pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns, but I would like for individual columns to remove repeat values in a particular column. I am stuck because my code seems to make sense logically to me but doesn't seem to work.

Here is the data I am working with:

```
d = {'Word': ["hi", "hi", "hi", "hello", "where", "where", "for", "how", "how", "how", "how", "how"], 
    'index': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 , 4, 4, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('index')
```

[image]

This is the result I would like, where for each group in the index column, repeat values are removed.

[image]

```
i = 0
while i < (len(set(df.index)) - 1):
    if len(df[["Word"]].loc[i]) > 1: 
        for k in range(1, (len(df[["Word"]].loc[i].reset_index()))):
            if df[["Word"]].loc[i].reset_index().at[k, "Word"] == df[["Word"]].loc[i].reset_index().at[0, "Word"]:
                df[["Word"]].loc[i].reset_index().at[k, "Word"] = ""
    i += 1
```

What I am doing here is taking all of the groups where the index value is repeated, and taking the range of each of those groups to compare each value to the first (index = 0) value. If the following values are the same as the first value, I am indicating that it should be turned into a blank. I am also resetting the index after I loc into each row so that I can index into every value to compare it to the first. This doesn't change the data frame no matter what I do and was wondering what was going on with my code and why the df isn't updating at all.

Comment: For your piece of code : you are using reset_index, which has in_place=False by default, this means you are modifying another dataframe returned by the method, not df

Comment: What if you have [hi, hi, how, hi, hi]? Do we output [hi, how, hi] or [hi, how]? I guess my question is how we handle non-consecutive duplicates.

Comment: This is not an issue with reset_index, because I do not want the index to remain. I want to know how to remove the duplicates in the Word column based on its group in the index column.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to get it to work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# going to use this for boolean indexing
erase = np.tile(np.array(False), 12)

#iterate over each unique word
for word in np.unique(df['Word']):
    found = df['Word'] == word

    # check if there is more than one occurance 
    if np.count_nonzero(found == True) > 1:

        # get indexes
        indexs = np.where(found.values == True)[0]
        firstIndex = indexs[0]
        lastIndex = indexs[len(indexs)-1]

        # update values to erase
        erase[firstIndex+1:lastIndex+1] = True

# update main dataframe
df[erase] = ''
```